# SharePoint/infopath: New item form, show past items

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath-rules

We use SharePoint 2010 list (not libraries). We have a list of equipment, and a list of support tickets. When a user creates a new ticket, I want the form to show the past tickets at a glance for that device to identify reoccurring issues.

Reading around I see a lot of things about repeatable tables/section, which are missing on my info path (they say it's for libraries only).

How would I accomplish this?